# How to get an app setting (ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT) with 'Staging' in staging slot, 'Production' in production slot using bicep?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-bicep

I'm trying to set different values for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT using bicep.

- 'Staging' in staging slot
- 'Production' in production slot

I always end up having ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = 'Production' in both staging and production...

production.json

```
"Settings": {
   "value": {
        "Setting__Prop1": false,
        "Setting__Prop2": true,
  }
},
```

main.bicep

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
    kind: 'api'
    name: name
    ...
}

resources appServiceSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
    name: '${appService.name}/appsettings'
    properties: union(settings, { ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Production' }
}

resource appServiceStickySettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
    name: 'slotConfigNames'
    parent: appService
    properties: {
     // Sticky app settings
     appSettingNames: [ 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' ]
    }
}

resource appServiceSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-03-01' = {
    name: '${name}/staging'
    kind: 'api'
    ...
}

resource appServiceSlotService 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config@2021-03-01' = {
    name: '${appServiceSlot.name}/appsettings'
    properties: union(settings, { ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Staging' })
}
```

End goal is to run some code only in production and not also in staging (like Service Bus listener that runs as background service)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible to set the same setting with different values depending on the slot.

But I was able to have a sticky setting in app service only, and not in staging. So I could test the existence of the setting and set up listener of the service hub accordingly.

main.bicep

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
    kind: 'api'
    name: name
    ...
}

resources appServiceSettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
    name: '${appService.name}/appsettings'
    properties: union(settings, { SERVICE_HUB_LISTENER: 1 }
}

resource appServiceStickySettings 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2021-03-01' = {
    name: 'slotConfigNames'
    parent: appService
    properties: {
     // Sticky app settings
     appSettingNames: [ 'SERVICE_HUB_LISTENER' ]
    }
}

resource appServiceSlot 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots@2021-03-01' = {
    name: '${name}/staging'
    kind: 'api'
    ...
}

// removed that part
// resource appServiceSlotService 'Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config@2021-03-01' = {
//     name: '${appServiceSlot.name}/appsettings'
//     properties: union(settings, { ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: 'Staging' })
// }
```

SERVICE_HUB_LISTENER will remain in app service production slot only.
Hope it will help someone.